# How can I tell if a machine's single analog audio socket is out-only or a "combo"?

Tags: audio, microphone, headphones, connector, 3.5mm

The ASUS VivoMini VC66R [has](https://www.asus.com/us/Mini-PCs/VivoMini-VC66/specifications/) only one socket for an audio jack:

[image]

How can I tell whether this will support only audio-out (headphones), or combination audio in-and-out (in which case I can use an [adapter/socket splitter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAXzw.jpg))

Comment: [Spec page](https://www.asus.com/Mini-PCs/VivoMini-VC66R/) `an audio output jack`. I assume this means audio out only, like headphones, etc.

Comment: I recommend contacting the ASUS support for your country. See page 40 of the user manual: http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/Desktop/Vivo_PC/VC66/E13165_VC66_Series_UM_V4_WEB.pdf . There is no mention of audio input.

Comment: @DrZoo: But the [actual spec page](https://www.asus.com/Mini-PCs/VivoMini-VC66R/specifications/) is less specific. Also, previous model had both an input and an output socket.

Comment: @davidmneedham: I've just written them, let's see what they say.

Comment: Searching other sites for reviews, they all say audio-output jack. So I'm doubting it takes input and output.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote ASUS support, and they say:

> Dear sir/ madam,
>
> Thank you for your email.
>
> This device **makes use of a so called combo jack.** These jacks do no
>   allow the use of normal microphones as the connection is different
>   from a normal 3.5 jack.

So apparently it's not just audio out. I'm still not 100% sure I should take their word on it, but this was pretty explicit.